# Alexa, Unable to link your skill with Implicit Grant

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am developing custom skill in Alexa, which required Account Linking. I am using Implicit grant for account linking. I have my own login page for account linking [here](https://orangeappstudio.com/Alexa/). I also refer this [post](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html) for implicit grant account linking. but I have no luck. when i try to login it will redirect to it's redirect url but every time I receive **Unable to Link your skill**.

My Account linking authorization URI looks like this

**Authorization URI:**https://orangeappstudio.com/Alexa?state=N.virginia&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&response_type=token&scope=userinfo.email&redirect_uri=https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=xxxxxxxx

and when user enter the correct crediential it will redirect user to the redirect url as mension in the Account linking console.
My redirect uri is

**Redirect URI**:https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=xxxxxx#state=N.virginia&access_token=2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA&token_type=Bearer

I have no idea what am i doing wrong.I have gone through the forums about the same, but couldn't find what exactly the issue is. Could any one please help me out in this regard.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: look for same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It must be due to value of `state` Query String parameter being sent to Amazon Skill redirect URL along with `access_token`.

According to [Implicit Grant Flow](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/account-linking/configure-implicit-grant.html), when the Alexa app calls the specified `authorization URI`, it includes `state`, `client_id`, `response_type`, `scope`, and `redirect_uri` as query string parameters. You must pass un-altered value of `state` parameter when redirect along with `access_token`.